# Ora-01722 Invalid Number

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

I'm trying to perform an insert and I'm getting an invalid number error.
I know where but I don't know why or how to fix this. Everything is fine (I guess).

Here are the PL/SQL blocks:

```
DECLARE
  L_J_ID NUMBER := J_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO some_table
    (J_ID, E_TABLE_COLUMN, F_TABLE_COLUMN)
  VALUES
    (L_J_ID, 'a', 'b');

  INSERT INTO CFG_FILTER_JOIN
    (J_ID, E_TABLE_COLUMN, F_TABLE_COLUMN)
  VALUES
    (L_J_ID, 'c', 'd');
END;
/

DECLARE 
   var NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ID --number
    INTO var
    FROM some_table
   WHERE F_TABLE_COLUMN = 'a'
     AND E_TABLE_COLUMN = 'b';

  INSERT INTO my_table
    (ID, --in table definition: number(8)
     NAME, --varchar2(30)
     TYPE, --varchar2(30)
     TABLE_name, --varchar2(30)
     J_ID,  --number(8) --here is where I get the invalid number
     COLUMN,  --varchar2(30)
     COLUMN_TYPE, --varchar2(1)
     FILTER_LIST_ID) --number(8)
  VALUES
    (SEQ.NEXTVAL,
     'COL_LIST',
     'JL',
     var,  --here is where I get the invalid number
     'NB_CTL',
     'DEST',
     'V',
     4);
END;
/
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? What is `L_JOIN_ID`? That's not declared anywhere. As a minimum you should be able to remove one of the anonymous blocks you have here... as to why - you're inserting an invalid number into a number column so you need to check the data you're putting into the number columns...

Comment: `L_JOIN_ID` was unedited. I have written in the comments where's the error, you must have missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your insert statement into pseudo code you get:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
  (ID             = SEQ.NEXTVAL,
   NAME           = 'COL_LIST',
   TYPE           = 'JL',
   TABLE          = var,
   J_ID           = 'NB_CTL',
   COLUMN         = 'DEST',
   COLUMN_TYPE    = 'V',
   FILTER_LIST_ID = 4)
```

which has the numeric J_ID column being assigned a string value 'NB_CTL'.

Comment: Nice catch, 2 columns in the wrong order... I missed it. tks

Answer (score 0):

Table is a reserved keyword enclose table in double Quotes("table"). And column mismatch was happened. By rewriting your plsql block is

```
    DECLARE
          L_J_ID NUMBER := J_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
        BEGIN

          INSERT INTO some_table
            (J_ID, E_TABLE_COLUMN, F_TABLE_COLUMN)
          VALUES
            (L_J_ID, 'a', 'b');

          INSERT INTO CFG_FILTER_JOIN
            (J_ID, E_TABLE_COLUMN, F_TABLE_COLUMN)
          VALUES
            (L_J_ID, 'c', 'd');
        END;
        /

        DECLARE 
           var NUMBER;
        BEGIN
          SELECT ID --number
            INTO var
            FROM some_table
           WHERE F_TABLE_COLUMN = 'a'
             AND E_TABLE_COLUMN = 'b';

          INSERT INTO my_table
            (ID, --in table definition: number(8)
             NAME, --varchar2(30)
             TYPE, --varchar2(30)
             j_id  --number(8)
              "TABLE", --varchar2(30)--here is where I get the invalid number
             COLUMN,  --varchar2(30)
             COLUMN_TYPE, --varchar2(1)
             FILTER_LIST_ID) --number(8)
          VALUES
            (SEQ.NEXTVAL,
           'COL_LIST',
            'JL',
             var,
            'NB_CTL',
             'DEST',
             'V',
              4);

        END;
```

Reserved keywords are:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm